# Code migration issue from Swift 2.x to 4.0

Tags: swift, migration, mapkit

After I have a look back to my repo project in Swift, I realize that there is this one code issue that I have had a hard time figuring out the error related to the API change for a particular function of **MKLocalSearch**

In specific, in my below snippet which contains mainly the function, which *basically do the search and update to the searched location*

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked (_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
    //here check if local search existed, it then cancel the search
    if let search = localSearch {
        search.cancel()
    }
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text

    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    //set the network activity visible
    UIApplication.shared
        .isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    //start the search and deliver the response with error handling asynchronously

    /* --------------------------This is where the bug occurs --------------*/
    localSearch!.start {
        [weak self] (response : MKLocalSearchResponse?, error: NSError?) in

        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        //safely extract location search results based on response
        guard let myResponse = response else {
            print("error in search: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? MissingError)")
            return
        }
        //            guard let location = myResponse.mapItems.first else {
        //                print("There are no results")
        //                return
        //            }
        guard let location = myResponse.mapItems else{
            print("There are no results")
            return
        }
        self?.updateMapWithItem(location, region: myResponse.boundingRegion)
    }
```

So I got the error with its full message 
`Cannot convert value of type '(MKLocalSearchResponse?, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler' (aka '(Optional<MKLocalSearchResponse>, Optional<Error>) -> ()')`

And the Swift 3.0 compiler suggests me to do the following, but its solution is completely sufficient as it's just keep telling me to insert more and more and more of this following statement without completely resolving the issue. 
`Insert ' as! MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler'`

I actually wanted to migrate the whole project code from Swift 2.x to 4.0, but I meant I needed to get this migration from 2.x to 3.0 figured out first.

Comment: Why not look at the documentation for the `MKLocalSearch start` method and then `MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler`. Note the slight difference in what it should be versus what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
localSearch?.start(completionHandler: {
    [weak self] (response, error) in
    ....
})
```

Instead of

```
localSearch!.start {
    [weak self] (response : MKLocalSearchResponse?, error: NSError?) in
    ....
}
```